# ReactDOM.render() Not Working - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, render, react-dom

I have been following a course on Udemy.com and have run into a problem that I am unable to fix. I have webpack installed as well as babel and followed the instructions through a second time to double check that I didn't make a mistake.

When trying to run this code in my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>HELLO!</div>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I get the Error:

> ERROR in ./app/index.js
>       Module parse failed: /Users/Kyle/Documents/React Native Workspace/es6Project/app/index.js Unexpected token (5:2)
>       You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>
> ```
> | 
> | ReactDOM.render(
> |   <div>HELLO!</div>, document.getElementById('root')
> | );
> | 
>  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./app/index.js
> ```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "es6Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '.build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        module: {
          loaders: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    contentBase: './build',
    inline: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is all your config jammed into `LoaderOptionsPlugin`? Just use a normal webpack config.

Answer (score 2):

Your webpack configuration is wrong. The error you are getting is regarding [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), being unable to be parsed due to misconfiguration.

Also since you are creating a new project, why are you using a [plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/loader-options-plugin/) that its purpose is to migrate from webpack 1.x versions to 2.x ?

If you use webpack version 2.x modify `module.exports` to contain:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            use:[{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        compact: false,
                        presets: [["es2015", {"modules": false, "loose" : true}], 'react']

                    }
                }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your application where you have rendering your app.
 check you html file. the code which you have return it is good.

please go thorugh **reactjs tutorial point**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_overview.htm